# For Loop with multiple outputs

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data frame roughly like this:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(a = 1:9000, b = 1:9000, c = 1:9000, d = 1:9000, 
    e = 1:9000, f = 1:9000, g = 1:9000, h = 1:9000, i = 1:9000), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9000L))
```

*Edit: These are the exact values this was just to show rough dimension, and there are far more columns as well, the values don't just run 1:9000*

To sample randomly & add in a column of row averages I have been using the following:

```
sample_1 <- sample(1:9000, 200, replace=F)
sampled_df_1 <- df[c(sample_1),]
sampled_df_1$Means_1 <- rowMeans(sampled_df_1)
```

I need to do this 100 times over, and then create a data frame of the means. I think I need to use a for loop for this as in:

```
for(i in 1:100){
sample_[i] <- sample(1:9000, 200, replace=F)
sampled_df_[i] <- df[c(sample_[i]),]
sampled_df_[i]$Means_[i] <- rowMeans(sampled_df_[i])}
```

but the [i] doesn't append the vector number.
I have also tried {i} and '+i'
Is this possible to do? I think assign(paste()) may be the key here but I am struggling with it
And when I am past it is there an easy way to create a data frame of just the means columns without typing out all their names?

Answer (score 2):

It’ll be simpler to use `sapply()` which will do both the iteration
and also combine the results.

```r
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(6), b = rnorm(6), c = rnorm(6))
df
#>            a           b          c
#> 1  1.3709584  1.51152200 -1.3888607
#> 2 -0.5646982 -0.09465904 -0.2787888
#> 3  0.3631284  2.01842371 -0.1333213
#> 4  0.6328626 -0.06271410  0.6359504
#> 5  0.4042683  1.30486965 -0.2842529
#> 6 -0.1061245  2.28664539 -2.6564554

set.seed(43)

N_REPEATS <- 4
N_ROWS_SAMPLED <- 3

sapply(seq_len(N_REPEATS), function(i) {
  rowMeans(df[sample(nrow(df), N_ROWS_SAMPLED), ])
})
#>         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#> 4  0.4020330 -0.3127153  0.4749617 -0.1586448
#> 6 -0.1586448  0.4749617 -0.3127153  0.4978732
#> 1  0.4978732 -0.1586448  0.7494103  0.4020330
```

If you want to keep the sampled subsets, split this into two parts:

```r
set.seed(43)

samples <- lapply(seq_len(N_REPEATS), function(i) {
  df[sample(nrow(df), N_ROWS_SAMPLED), ]
})

sapply(samples, rowMeans)
#>         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#> 4  0.4020330 -0.3127153  0.4749617 -0.1586448
#> 6 -0.1586448  0.4749617 -0.3127153  0.4978732
#> 1  0.4978732 -0.1586448  0.7494103  0.4020330
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response but I am confused how this will pull the values out of the dataframe I mentioned with 9000 values? The dataframe contains gene expression values so I'm wanting the mean expression form all the randomly selected samples? I'm pretty new to R so I may just have made my question unclear or misunderstood your response!

Comment: Start in the middle and run pieces of `rowMeans(df[sample(nrow(df), 3), ])` to see how each step works `nrow(df)`, then `sample(nrow(df), 3)` then `df[sample(nrow(df), 3), ]` You can follow what it does and that it samples rows of the original `df`.  Change the value `3` to change the number of rows sampled from the 9000 and the `seq_len(4)` to change the number of times it is repeated.

Comment: Well explained @Roasty247. I edited out the magic numbers for clarity.

Comment: @Ella I used a smaller example to be able to show the results in this post, but as Roasty explained, the logic will work for a bigger input `df` just as well.

Comment: Thank you to both Mikko Marttila & @Roasty247 ! Very new in this area & sapply isn't really something I'd worked with. I see now how df was brought in. Thanks also for introduction of set.seed, this will make it easier for tracking of sample use.

Answer (score 1):

With a `for()`loop it can be done like this:

```
df <- structure(list(a = 1:9000, b = 1:9000, c = 1:9000, d = 1:9000, 
               e = 1:9000, f = 1:9000, g = 1:9000, h = 1:9000, i = 1:9000), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                -9000L))
nsims <- 100
sample_df_rows <- 200
Row <- seq(1:sample_df_rows)

output <- data.frame(Row)
for(i in 1:nsims){
  sample <- sample(1:9000, sampled_df_rows, replace=F)
  sample_df <- df[c(sample),]
  sample_df$Means <- rowMeans(sample_df)
  colnames(sample_df) <- c(letters[1:9],paste0("Means_",i))
  output <- cbind(output,sample_df[10])
}

output
```